# I can simulate a KEY_X hit to the right /dev/input/event#, but how do I simulate 'x'?

Tags: input, keyboard, linux-device-driver

I've read plenty of articles and source here and in other places, and can open the event device on my embedded Linux device and stuff KEY_? definitions that are picked up by whatever app I happen to be running.

But oddly enough, I can't find any information on how to simulate the pressing of a key that results in a lower-case character being sent... i.e. 'x' instead of the 'X' I get from KEY_X.  linux/input.h didn't help either.

If this is possible, how would I do it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sending keypresses is part of uinput, not the event subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as sending a character. When receiving the KEY_X event, the application will map that event to a character. It may be 'x' or 'X' depending on the caps lock status and the shift key but it may as well be something else.

Comment: That's what it seemed like, thanks for the verification.